# Firefox scrolling slow after installing NVIDIA proprietary software?

Tags: nvidia, firefox

I recently installed NVIDIA proprietary software via "Additional hardware" and suddenly the scrolling in Firefox has slowed down meaning on a web-page when I roll my center mouse ball, the page scrolls down with delay.

Earlier when I was using the default open-source driver nouveau, I was not seeing the problem. Chrome, however, still works fine. What can be done?

Comment: I am noticing huge performance drop else in system as well like window swapping etc..If i remove the installed NVIDIA version from "additional software", would that automatically bring me back to nouveau or do i need to do anything else?

Comment: If you open nvidia-settings, (Nvidia X Server Settings), does your card have a "PowerMizer" section? If so then test by changing the 'Preferred Mode' to "Prefer Maximum Performance' & see if FF scrolling improves.

Comment: Thanks Doug, the speed has improved a bit after making ur suggested changes but the sluggishness is still there. I'll monitor my system for a day to see how it goes.

Comment: Interesting thing is that the sluggishness is comparatively less in gnome-shell than Unity 3d

Comment: What machine do you have? [Optimus laptops do not work out-of-the-box](http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)

Comment: i have Lenovo T61. Well, i tried installing the latest version 290 from the NVIDIA website but the issue persisted so I have removed the driver and not using the open-source Nouveau which works far better than NVIDIA

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, are you still looking for an answer? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!